# Boostrap sidebar only toggles the top part

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, sidebar

I have a problem, I don't really target if it is the jQuery, CSS, or HTML. But I am having the problem that the sidebar toggles only the top part of the hamburger icon. This is not the boostrap toggler, this is a additionally sidebar that only appears on lg screens and up. At the bottom of this post I attached a CodePen where the problem is clearly visible.

What I have tryed?

Setting the list-group height to 100% where all the items I want to toggle simply doesn't work. Changing the jQuery didn't help either, but I am sure that is the animate function I want, it simple doesn't toggle completely

```
<div class="col-12 mr-4 sidebar">
      <div class="mini-submenu">
          <span class="icon-bar2"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar2"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar2"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group mt-5">
          <span href="#" class="list-group-item active">
              <img style="width:150px;" class="svgcenter mt-4" src="assets/svgs/logolight.svg">
              <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </span>
          </span>
          <p class="white py-4 px-5 text-center  list-group-item light">
              Lorem ipsum diocritatem eu, fierent molestie petentium id his. Ut aeterno nostrum nam, solet sapientem ea quo. Cum te meis illud, aeterno accusata ut vix.
          </p>
          <div href="#" class="list-group-item py-4">
              <li><h5 class="white text-center"><i class="white fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>Mave Avenue, New York</h5></li>
              <li><h5 class="white text-center"><i class="white fas fa-phone-square mr-2"></i>United States (+1) 3333.1111</h5></li>
              <li><h5 class="white text-center"><i class="white fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>hello@ourcompany.com</h5></li>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item text-center pt-4 ">
          <h6>Follow Us</h6>
              <div class="text-center py-3">
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              </div>     
          <div class="list-group-item py-4">                       
              <a href="#" class="d-block white py-2">
                  <i class="fa fa-users"></i> About Us
              </a>
              <a class="white d-block" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Us
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.sidebartop {
  z-index: 50;
}

.mini-submenu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 7px;
}

.mini-submenu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mini-submenu .icon-bar2 {
  border-radius: 1px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: right;
}

.mini-submenu .icon-bar2:nth-child(2) {
  width: 16px;
  transform: translatex(4px);
}

.mini-submenu .icon-bar2 {
  background-color: #000;
}

#slide-submenu {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 40;
}

.list-group {
  display: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #303030;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.list-group-item.active {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #303030;
  border-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.list-group-item {
  background: #303030;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

nav h5 i {
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

and the jQuery. Sorry for long code

```
$(function(){
      //effect to close submenu
    $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {                 
          $(this).closest('.list-group').animate({'width':'toggle',}),function(){
            $('.list-group').animate({'width':'toggle'});   
          };

        });
   //effect to open submenu
    $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){       
          $(this).next('.list-group').animate({'width':'toggle'});
    })
})
```

And here is the CodePen where the problem is visible
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrZxPr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I changed the CSS, the problem was that By using position:absolute throughout your fiddle, I was removing the child elements from the flow of the DOM and interfering with the ability of the parent element to incrementally hide its children, fixed by changing position to fixed.

```
.list-group {
  display: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #303030;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```